# How can I read a HttpOnly cookie of my Flutter webview?

Tags: javascript, flutter, http, dart, cookies

I have a Flutter app that consists of a WebView. I would like to read a specific cookie from this WebView, which is flagged as HttpOnly. How can I achieve this?

I was able to sucessfully read **non-**HttpOnly cookies via `WebViewController.evaluateJavascript()`, but I am interested in the HttpOnly cookies as well. The HttpOnly cookies do not show up using this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out myself after some digging: One has to use the `WebViewCookieManager`, a seperate package.

Example code:

```
import 'package:webview_cookie_manager/webview_cookie_manager.dart';
...
final _cookieManager = WebviewCookieManager();
final gotCookies = await _cookieManager.getCookies("https://example.com/");
for (var item in gotCookies) {
  print(item);
}
```

Also see
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27795 and https://pub.dev/packages/webview_cookie_manager

Answer (score -1):

You can read cookies by using `await WebViewController.evaluateJavascript(source: 'document.cookie');`

Here are some more details on what you can do: [Webview In Flutter](https://www.coderzheaven.com/2019/03/28/webview-in-flutter-part-2/)

```dart
final String cookies = await WebViewController.evaluateJavascript(source: 'document.cookie');
final cookieList = cookies.split('; ');
final result = cookieList.firstWhere((e) => e.startsWith(...), orElse: () => null);
print(result);
```

Comment: that is exactly what I tried. However HttpOnly cookies do not show up when reading the cookies with javascript.